# Why am i getting "Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package HTTP" error when trying to add the Plots package in Julia?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm using Julia v1.5.2 and using this code to add the Plots package

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("Plots")
```

And I'm getting an error message that is given below.
I've tried reinstalling Julia and also tried the other stable version (v1.0), but I'm still getting the same type of error message. I even tried using the Pkg manager instead of using `import Pkg`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference either.

```
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package HTTP [cd3eb016]:
 HTTP [cd3eb016] log:
 ├─HTTP [cd3eb016] has no known versions!
 └─found to have no compatible versions left with Pluto [c3e4b0f8]
   └─Pluto [c3e4b0f8] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.6, 0.4.0-0.4.3, 0.5.0-0.5.21, 0.6.0-0.6.4, 0.7.0-0.7.10, 0.8.0-0.8.10, 0.9.0-0.9.11, 0.10.0-0.10.13, 0.11.0-0.11.14, 0.12.0-0.12.3] or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.6, 0.4.0-0.4.3, 0.5.0-0.5.21, 0.6.0-0.6.4, 0.7.0-0.7.10, 0.8.0-0.8.10, 0.9.0-0.9.11, 0.10.0-0.10.13, 0.11.0-0.11.14, 0.12.0-0.12.3]
Stacktrace:
 [1] propagate_constraints!(::Pkg.Resolve.Graph, ::Set{Int64}; log_events::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Resolve\graphtype.jl:1005
 [2] propagate_constraints! at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Resolve\graphtype.jl:946 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [3] simplify_graph!(::Pkg.Resolve.Graph, ::Set{Int64}; clean_graph::Bool) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Resolve\graphtype.jl:1460
 [4] simplify_graph! at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Resolve\graphtype.jl:1460 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [5] resolve_versions!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:375
 [6] targeted_resolve at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1114 [inlined]
 [7] tiered_resolve(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1100
 [8] _resolve at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1120 [inlined]
 [9] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1135
 [10] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Windows, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:188
 [11] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:139
 [12] #add#21 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [13] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [14] #add#20 at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [15] add at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [16] add(::String; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:65
 [17] add(::String) at D:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.5\Pkg\src\API.jl:65
 [18] top-level scope at REPL[19]:1
```

Comment: For future reference, https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/managing-packages/#conflicts-1 walks you through package conflicts and how to resolve them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove `Pluto`

```
using Pkg
pkg"rm Pluto"
pkg"add Plots"
```

Then update the packages:

```
pkg"update"
```

I would also now try to explicitly install `Http` and check it version:

```
pkg"add HTTP"
pkg"status HTTP"
```

Pluto seems to require at least `HTTP` version `0.8.8` which does not look like anything *special*. So now you should be able to install back Pluto

```
pkg"add Pluto"
```

If anything goes wrong please write it. For sure Pluto is working together with Plots. This is my package status here (you could provide similar info):

```
julia> Pkg.status.(["Pluto","HTTP","Plots"]);
Status `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia1.5.2\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [c3e4b0f8] Pluto v0.12.3
Status `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia1.5.2\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [cd3eb016] HTTP v0.8.19
Status `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia1.5.2\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.6.9
```

Sometimes some other package might be holding down versions of everything.

Comment: I removed Pluto. And upon updating I'm getting: "no changes to `C:\Users\<name>\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml` and `C:\Users\<name>\.julia\environments\v1.5\Manifest.toml`. And I'm getting the same error message as in the post above when trying to add HTTP.

Comment: Also, these are my statuses:  
`Status C:\Users\<name>\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml (empty project) 
Status C:\Users\<name>\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml (empty project)
Status C:\Users\<name>.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml (empty project)` from the looks of this, I think I should've created a virtual environment? Could that be the issue?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I did two things, so I'm not sure which one worked.
1) I added the .julia folder in Users/<username> as an excluded folder for windows security. 
2) I deleted the same .julia folder, opened Julia app as an administrator, and wrote `update` in the Pkg manager. It took a minute or two to update a few things and recreated the .julia folder. Then, I added the HTTP, Plots, and Pluto in order, just as you suggested. It didn't give any errors.

Comment: Deleting the `.julia` folder helped. Sometimes the Julia package configuration crashes and the only way is to restore it.

Comment: updating packages fixed it for me. did: 
`$ julia`
`julia> ]`
`pkg> update`
`pkg> add Plots`  and it worked

Answer (score 0):

`] update Pluto` (or the name of the dependency causing this problem)

Then try again: `] add Plots`

**Explanation:**

In the situation where the problem is caused by a dependency (here, `Pluto`) with a restriction of `restricted to versions ... by an explicit requirement`, the explicit requirement is likely due to that dependency (`Pluto`) itself. So you can simply update that dependency (`Pluto`) independently before updating the upstream packages (`HTTP` or `Plots`):